# In conky, how do I nest a variable within a template?

Tags: templates, variables, conky

In conky, how do I nest a variable within a template?

EXAMPLES:

```
${template2 enp0s25} <- WORKS (fixed string)
${template2 ${gw_iface}} < FAILS (nested variable)
${template2 ${execpi 10 ls -d /sys/class/net/enp* 2> /dev/null | sed -e 's,/sys/class/net/,,'}} <- FAILS (nested variable command)
```

I've also tried (and failed):

```
${combine ${template2 ${gw_iface}}}
${combine ${template2} ${gw_iface}}
```

Here is "template2":

```
template2 = [[
${if_existing /proc/net/route \1}Wired Ethernet ("\1"):
 - MAC: ${execi 5 cat /sys/class/net/\1/address}    IP: ${addr  \1}
 - Max: ${execi 5 /sbin/ethtool  '\1' 2>/dev/null | sed -n -e 's/^.*Speed: //p'}${goto 190}${if_match ${downspeedf \1} > 0}${font :bold:size=14}${endif}Down: ${downspeedf \1}kB/s${font}${goto 370}${if_match ${upspeedf \1} > 0}${font :bold:size=14}${endif}Up: ${upspeedf \1}kB/s${font}
${endif}]]
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Templates are a little limited as you cannot evaluate the parameters before they are passed through. One workaround is to use a bit of `lua` code to do the eval explicitly and then parse the template. For example,

```lua
conky.config = { 
    lua_load = '/tmp/myfunction.lua',
    ...
};
conky.text = [[
 ${lua myeval template2 ${gw_iface}}
]]
```

Create the lua file, `/tmp/myfunction.lua` holding

```lua
function conky_myeval(tpl, var1)
 v = conky_parse(var1)
 cmd = "${"..tpl.." "..v.."}"
 return conky_parse(cmd)
end
```

The `lua` function takes the name of the template, `tpl`, and the parameter to evaluate, `var1`. It evaluates the latter using `conky_parse()` to, say, string "xxx", then constructs a new string `"${template2 xxx}"`, which is parsed and returned as the value of the `${lua}` call.

The same can be done for the longer example `${execpi ...}` too.

Comment: Hello meuh.  Thank you for your response.  I was trying to avoid using external scripts.  But it appears that may be my only option.  Thank you for the information.