# How do I cycle through random fonts in Conky via LUA?

Tags: lua, conky

This question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68146754/in-conky-how-do-i-nest-a-variable-within-a-template) seems to tangentially touch upon it but I cannot get it to work. Here is my LUA file:

```
function conky_myeval()
   local myTable = { " Old London :normal:size=7", "Ethnocentric :normal:size=7"}
   var1 = myTable[ math.random( #myTable)] 
   return var1
end
```

and the related conky part:

```
${font ${lua conky_myeval}} Hello World!
```

Thank you for any assistance and I apologize if this has been asked before; The most similar I found I posted above.

Comment: what's the problem with that? are there any error messages? how does the behaviour differ from what you expect?  the Lua code is syntactically correct. I don't know conky. the only thing that looks a bit off are the spaces befor and after the font names. I haven't seen this in the documentation or any other example. but maybe that's ignored.

Comment: The problem is with Conky, I think. It just displays "Hello World!" as the default font. So the **${font}** command is clearly running, but it's not taking the input of **conky_myeval** which would be **Old London** etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found it easier to have a lua script pass conky a string that can be parsed by a `lua_parse` object that then generates the intended object rather than trying to pass a value to the intended object.

In the case of random fonts, I'd do something like the following, which worked when tested.

*Lua file:*

```
function conky_myfont()
   local myTable = {"DejaVu Serif:normal:size=12", "MuseJazz Text:normal:size=12"}
   var1 = myTable[ math.random( #myTable)] 
   return "${font "..var1.."}"
end
```

*Conky part:*

```
${lua_parse conky_myfont}Hello World!${font}
```

Comment: That worked beautifully. Thanks!